# Adding more than one condition in Projection.Conditionals for queryover

Tags: c#, nhibernate, conditional-statements, queryover

I am trying to write a case with more than one `when` clause; something like this:

```
...
case
    when 'starks' then 1
    when 'wildlings' then 2
    when 'lannisters' then 3
    Else 0
End
...
```

I've done a single conditional before with something like

```
.OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(
    Restrictions.Where<House>(r => r.Name.IsLike("starks")),
    Projections.Constant(0),
    Projections.Constant(1))).Asc();
```

But I can't figure out how to add an extra condition / `when` clause in there :/
I've tried adding an extra outer conditional, extra restriction etc, but always end up with syntax error..

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Projections.Conditional` returns `IProjection`, and its signature is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Conditionally return the true or false part, dependention on the criterion
/// </summary>
/// <param name="criterion">The criterion.</param><param name="whenTrue">The when true.
///    </param><param name="whenFalse">The when false.</param>
/// <returns/>
public static IProjection Conditional(ICriterion criterion
                                    , IProjection whenTrue
                                    , IProjection whenFalse);
```

And that means, that the third parameter can again be this Conditional projection:

```
.OrderBy
(
    Projections.Conditional(
        Restrictions.Where<House>(r => r.Name.IsLike("starks")),
        Projections.Constant(1),
        Projections.Conditional(
            Restrictions.Where<House>(r => r.Name.IsLike("wildlings")),
            Projections.Constant(2),
            Projections.Conditional(
                Restrictions.Where<House>(r => r.Name.IsLike("lannisters")),
                Projections.Constant(3),
                Projections.Constant(0)
                )
            )
        )
)
.Asc()
```

The generated SQL will look like:

```
ORDER BY 
(case when this_.Name LIKE 'starks'     then 1 else 
(case when this_.Name LIKE 'wildlings'  then 2 else 
(case when this_.Name LIKE 'lannisters' then 3 else 0 end) end) end) asc
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the explanation too, taught me how to fish, that did.

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy NHiberante, great tool ;)

Comment: how can we use multiple restrictions like
Case when (gl.parent is null and gltype !='Parent') then 'I'
Case when (gl.parent in not null and po.amount < 1000) then 'X'